# Our Site link at the bottom of SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, stackexchange

As we are now launched, we've been added to the list of Stack Exchange sites at the bottom of all SE pages (scroll down there now to see what I'm referring to, I can wait!).  Unfortunately, the link is just "scifi", there's no mention of fantasy.  We are not just the sci-fi site, we are sci-fi + fantasy, and I think that link should include fantasy as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "scifi & fantasy" now.

(Providing an answer, since Jin hasn't, so that it can be accepted so that community doesn't bump this question).

(Or this can be deleted if someone adds [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)).

Comment: Darn, mods need to add that tag.

Comment: @Keen [meta-status-completed]

Comment: The question has had `status-completed` since three days after it was asked, so this can be deleted now.

Answer (score 3):

There's precedent for the abbreviation at the bottom not being the same as the subdomain (like gamedev.stackexchange.com - called game development) so I think it should be 'scifi-fantasy'

Answer (score -4):

Should be, "■ [spec-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)" then. To save space.

Comment: [I wish](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/565/what-should-our-site-name-be)